# JanusGraph Edges not removed after TTL expires

Tags: graph-databases, janusgraph

This is a question regarding the TTL set on edges in JanusGraph. I have set up a test where I create an edge label `edgeLabel` with a TTL duration - in my case 5 seconds.

I then create an edge with this label, and wait until the TTL should have expired. However, it seems that the vertex has not been removed from the graph. I'll give an example below that sheds some light on what I am trying to do.

### Example

Let's say `g` is the TinkerPop traversal object.
I have 2 vertices, with an `_id` property field of `v1` and `v2`.
What I see after creating an `edgeLabel` edge between `v1` and `v2` and waiting 10 seconds is that the vertices still have the edge attached:

`g.V().has("_id", "v1").next().edges(Direction.BOTH, "edgeLabel").hasNext() == true`

Additionally, checking the count of the number of edges in the graph before and after waiting for 10 seconds results in the same count, using the following:

`g.E().count().next().longValue()`

I confirmed that the TTL value is set properly with the `JanusGraphManagement`:

`final JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph.openManagement();
mgmt.getTTL(mgmt.getEdgeLabel("edgeLabel")).getSeconds() == 5`

### Configuration/Setup

I am running JanusGraph with Cassandra as the backend database storage, with the property `storage.backend = cql` against a local database instance, with all other properties as the defaults.

---

My question is: why is the edge not getting removed? Is there something that I need to do that I am missing such as refreshing the state of the graph database?

To the best of my knowledge, TTL should work with Cassandra as the backend database storage, and it should be enough to see that the TTL is set properly for the edge with a given label in the JanusGraphManagement.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the edge appeared not to be removed is actually because of the process used to check whether the edge was removed. To be clear, the process went as follows:

1. create edge `e` between vertices `v1` and `v2`
2. retrieve `v1` and traverse its edges to check that `e` exists
3. wait until the TTL time has passed
4. retrieve `v1` and traverse its edges again to check that `e` has expired and is gone

The trouble comes in because in step (2), a local transaction had been created where we accessed `e`. In step (4), we are now traversing `v1`s edges, and since we are working in the same transaction, `e` still appears to exist.

The solution is to ensure that the transaction is committed before executing step (4).